# How can I make this CSS only carousel show the first slide by default?

Tags: html, css, carousel

I have a CSS only carousel (which is very nice!), the only problem is that the first slide is not selected by default.

How could I achieve this without using JavaScript?

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item red slide-in" id="item1"><h1>Item 1</h1></div>
    <div class="item green slide-in" id="item2"><h1>Item 2</h1></div>
    <div class="item yellow slide-in" id="item3"><h1>Item 3</h1></div>
    <div class="item red slide-in" id="item4"><h1>Item 4</h1></div>
    <div class="controls">
        <a href="#item1" class="btn">•</a>
        <a href="#item2" class="btn">•</a>
        <a href="#item3" class="btn">•</a>
        <a href="#item4" class="btn">•</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the core css:

```
.carousel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel .item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* animations */

.carousel .slide-in {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-90%, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-90%, 0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-90%, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(-90%, 0px, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(-90%, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.carousel .slide-in:target ~ .slide-in {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(90%, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(90%, 0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(90%, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(90%, 0px, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(90%, 0px, 0px);
}

.carousel .slide-in:target,
.carousel .slide-in:focus {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    z-index: 3;
}

.carousel .slide-in:target + .slide-in {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with the carousel working:

http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/fs6wge3f/6/

Comment: updated fiddle working using Josh's technique: http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/fs6wge3f/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that *partially* works, would be to select the first element if it isn't a target.

To select an element that isn't a target, negate it using `:not(:target)`.

To select the first element, just combine it with `:first-of-type`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sq3fehL5/)

```
.carousel .slide-in:first-of-type:not(:target) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    z-index: 3;
}
```

The caveat with this approach is that the first element no longer seems to slide.

---

Alternatively, the only other thing I can think of would be to have an input element with the attribute `autofocus="autofocus"`. Since the element will initially be in focus, utilize it by styling the first element using the selector `.carousel input[type="checkbox"]:focus + .slide-in`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrshvvk0/)

```
.carousel input[type="checkbox"]:focus + .slide-in,
.carousel .slide-in:target,
.carousel .slide-in:focus {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    z-index: 3;
}
```

The caveat with this approach is that the first slide will move as soon as the hidden input element loses focus.

Comment: yes!! this wasn't perfect but the input technique led me to a better solution. I've reversed the order of the slides to prevent the funny animation! http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/fs6wge3f/9/

Comment: @KimT Nice! I was working on a third solution, but this is much better. Glad it worked!